# Changing variables of a polynomial in several indeterminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm stuck with the following problem:

Let $k$ be a field, $f\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $P=(a_1,\ldots, a_n)\in k^n$.

It must be shown that one can think of $f $ as
$$ f=\sum \lambda_I (x_1-a_1)^{i_1}\cdots (x_n-a_n)^{i_n}, $$
*i.e.,* that $f$ belongs to $k[y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ where $y_i:=x_i-a_i, \quad  i=1, \ldots,n.$

I've been trying to show that if $\hat{R}$ is a commutative ring with unity, $R$ is a subring of $\hat{R}$, and $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n \in \hat{R} $ are algebraically independent over $R$, then there is an (unique) ring isomorphism $$ \psi \colon  R[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \to R[\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n].$$ (I think this can be done using the so-called *Universal property of polynomials in several indeterminates* (which I've already proven), but I've got no luck at using this to show that such $ \psi$ actually exists) How will you prove the existence of such ring isomorphism?

I guess that the existence of such isomorphism $  \psi $ answers the original question.

Any help is highly appreciated, no matter if you see another way to tackle the original question. Thanks!

Comment: It’s not clear what your problem is. There’s certainly a map carrying each $x_i$ to $\xi_i$, no problem there, and your map is clearly surjective. Now you have to show that the kernel is trivial. For that you use algebraic independence of the $\xi_i$’s.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now, such map was certainly obvious, and it does indeed have trivial kernel. Thanks for your help, everything is clear now.